# Use iText to produce formatted TextFields?

Tags: java, format, itext, textfield

Is there any way in iText to format a TextField's input? I want to have a TextField accept a phone number "(###)###-####", but I don't want the user to have to format it when they enter it. Pdf supports masks on form fields, is there any way to do this in iText?

My current solution is to create the pdf in Acrobat, then populate known fields through iText. But that isn't ideal for this deployment. Ideally I'll have iText generate the entire form.

Thanks for all assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add JavaScript to your form that changes the content of fields. See for instance the [Calculator](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=142) example for a fun PDF that acts as a [Calculator](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/calculator.pdf) (obviously this app only works in a PDF viewer that supports JavaScript).

When you create a text field, you need to add an additional action with the `setAdditionalActions()` method. You can choose between different events: `K` for keystroke (e.g. useful if you want to change every character to uppercase when somebody fills out a form), `Bl` for blurred (useful to process the content of a field as soon as the focus is lost), etc.

You can write your own document-level JavaScript to format the fields. See [calculator.js](http://examples.itextpdf.com/resources/js/calculator.js) for the JavaScript used in the Calculator example. Or you can use one of the many `AF` methods that are predefined Adobe Reader, such as [`AFNumber_Format`](http://www.planetpdf.com/forumarchive/125041.asp) (I don't find an overview of the available methods right now).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! So there isn't a way to set a field to be a phone number field? Acrobat's pdf documentation allows you to set a flag for form formatting (see [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/using/WSC9CAD508-1941-43db-B599-2DCBF7BFC055.w.html#WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7de4.w) ) Or does Adobe do the same JavaScript trick behind the scenes, it just gives a convenience method for Acrobat?

Comment: Acrobat uses the `AF` methods if they are shipped with Adobe Reader, but introduces embedded JavaScript if there no such method available. There used to be a site explaining the available `AF` methods, but I can't find it anymore. Maybe it was moved or taken off-line.